# Is my Fittonia plant healthy?

Tags: houseplants

I bought a Fittonia about a week ago. Today, I noticed a couple of its leaves getting less vibrant and almost having the veins fade. Is there anything I may be doing to cause this? Does the overall plant look healthy or is there signs that I should be aware of meaning something?

[image: Epps then photo][image]